# check folder path if on onedrive or local

Tags: excel, vba

company moved folders to onedrive however some people still using local drives, so I need help to check the folder is exist on one drive or not. below code for using for onedrive. I cannot create if condition on this.

```
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Environ("UserProfile") & "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll")
            i = 1
            For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
                Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
                                           objFile.Path, _
                                           TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
```

Comment: Looking to your code I am not sure  I understand your question. So, what do you want doing in your code? To check if the company onedrive folder exists and if yes, to create hyperlinks for all existing files? If not, can you better explain what wanting to accomplish? To also do the same for the local folder in case of no onedrive folder existence?

Comment: @FaneDuru you are totally right.  code takes all picture hyperlinks inside excel and user choose them manually. I try to reach if one drive folder then take hyperlinks from onedrive camera roll folder if not hen take from c:\\ users\userprofile\picture\camera roll

Comment: by the way, I do it for file checks ı can find file for both onedrive and local with a function withou if inside code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set `objFolder` before the loop

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With objFSO
    If .folderexists(Environ("UserProfile") & "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll") Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Environ("UserProfile") & "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll")
    Else
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Environ("UserProfile") & "\picture\camera roll")
    End If
End With
```

Comment: unlikely, I tried it on machine without onedrive sync it assumes find onedrive folder and skipped else and given error.

Comment: you mean that `folderexists(Environ("UserProfile") & "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll")` returns `True` and so it sets `Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Environ("UserProfile") & "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll")`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I have 2 machine in front of me and one is synced and the other one is not. tryed it on without sync.

Comment: by the way found a way using your code.`if left(ectivewoorkbook.Fullname, 8) = "https:// then` just removed first row and put this one and it seems work. however in case of activework book in a unsynced folder it will cause an error.

Comment: Don't get you but glad if you came to solve your issue 
You may then want to accept the answer and/or upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. It will create hyperlinks for both cases, if both of them exist:

```
Sub CheckOneDriveVersusLocalToHyperlink()
 Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, sh As Worksheet, i As Long
 Const OneDrPath As String = "\OneDrive - company name\Pictures\Camera Roll"
 Const LocalPath As String = "c:\users\userprofile\picture\camera roll"

 Set sh = ActiveSheet

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If objFSO.FolderExists(Environ("UserProfile") & OneDrPath) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Environ("UserProfile") & OneDrPath)
    i = 1
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add sh.cells(i + 1, 1), Address:= _
                                objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next
 End If
 If objFSO.FolderExists(LocalPath) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(LocalPath)
    i = 1
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add sh.cells(i + 1, 3), Address:= _
                                objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, take care to use your real paths. I do not think that the OneDrive one is correct in the way you show it. Is it a path on the intranet?

It will create hyperlinks from OneDrive in A:A column, and ones for local path in C:C column.

Of course, if you need only to create hyperlinks for the OneDrive folder (only in case it exists), you just delete the last part treating the local path. Or use `Else` instead of `End If ... If`, in case you need the hyperlink for the local path, only in case that the first one does not exist.

Comment: one drive link is correct and using on other codes works like charm. local one is incorrect which I wrote it need to be Pictures instead of picture. will try it

Comment: @SelpaqM: OK. Please, send some feedback after testing...